# Why does an escaped string look different with a GET than with a POST

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine, escaping

I'm sending some game data from Unity3D to SQL DB via some php scripts.
To send it I use POST, to retrieve it I use GET

I have a few parameters, including user-ID, which is an escaped string. I escape it with unity's WWW.EscapeURL() before sending with www request from Unity3d. It is used as the DB key index.

I noticed it doesn't always work, sometimes fails to retrieve user data, and it comes down to ID's with spaces or odd characters.

I've confirmed with debug print in game that the escaped ID looks the same for post and request.. e.g. it changes a space to a '+'
"john smith" gets sent as "john+smith" via a unity3d www request, for both POST and GET.

but the odd part... If I log the variable that arrives in the php...
for GET and POST it arrives differently one as "john smith" and one as "john+smith"  why ?

So data gets stored in the DB, but then when I try to read it out again,, the username is wrong so I can't retrieve it...

Any idea why ?  Help appreciated, thanks.
win server. phpMyAdmin 4.4.2  mysql5 (if it matters)

Comment: GET is [`urlencoded`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), and POST isn't.

Comment: Are you setting a "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header when using POST?